# Pointer and post-increment funny business

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence

What, if anything, is theoretically wrong with this c/c++ statement:

```
*memory++ = BIT_MASK & *memory;
```

Where `BIT_MASK` is an arbitrary bitwise `AND` mask, and memory is a pointer.

The intent was to read a memory location, `AND` the value with the mask, store the result at the original location, then finally increment the pointer to point to the next memory location.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behaviour because you reference `memory` twice (once for reading, once for writing) in a single statement without an intervening sequence point, and the language standards do not specify when the increment will occur.  (You can read the same memory multiple times; the troubles occur when you try to mix some writing in with the reading - as in your example.)

You can use:

```
*memory++ &= BIT_MASK;
```

to achieve what you want to achieve without incurring undefined behaviour.

---

In the C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999  aka C99), §6.5 'Expressions', ¶2 says

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.  Furthermore, the prior value
>   shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.<sup>70)</sup>

That's the primary source in the C standard.  The footnote says:

> This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
> i = ++i + 1;
> a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
> i = i + 1;
> a[i] = i;
> ```

In addition, 'Annex C (informative) Sequence Points' has an extensive discussion of all this.

You would find similar wording in the C++ standard, though I'm not sure it has an analogue to 'Annex C'.

Comment: Or, better yet: `*memory &= BIT_MASK; ++memory;`

Comment: I've never heard of this undefined behaviour. Is there somewhere I could read more on this?

Comment: @Benjamin: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder; I prefer the one-statement version.

Comment: To be clear, it's not referencing `*memory` twice that's the problem, it's referencing `memory` twice.

Answer (score 6):

It's undefined behavior since you have `memory++` and `memory` in the same statement.

This is because C/C++ does not specify exactly when the `++` will occur. It can be before or after `*memory` is evaluated.

Here are two ways to fix it:

```
*memory = BIT_MASK & *memory;
memory++;
```

or just simply:

```
*memory++ &= BIT_MASK;
```

Take your pick.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info.  i was assuming the post-increment will occur after the entire rest of the statement was complete.  I am surprised it is not specified in the c/c++ standards.

Comment: @NTHOLDER: There is no mainstream language that defines postfix ++ to happen after the statement. For example, Java and C# both *immediately* increment the variable (but yield the old value). An example for this is `int i = 0; a[i++] = i;` which will store at index 0 the value 1.